Google cloud run auth, odd behaviour based on URL params
Today I spent a very large part of my day debugging a 403 error in which I am calling a cloud run service from another cloud run service.
To authenticate between the two services they are deployed with --no-allow-unauthenticated, and the calling service needs to generate an ID token to call the other service.
The service to be called is a FastAPI python service which has an endpoint defined as @app.get("/service/api/v1/queries/").
Here is the minimal repro of the caller:
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';

const WORKING_URL = `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/queries/`;
const NOT_WORKING_URL = `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/queries`;

const googleAuth = new GoogleAuth();
const idTokenClient = await googleAuth.getIdTokenClient(BASE_URL);

console.log(
  await idTokenClient.request({
    url: ALSO_NOT_WORKING_URL,
  })
);

So the final issue turned out to be the trailing slash. The FastAPI docs often define routes with a trailing slash - so this was the approach taken. If a caller omits it, FastAPI automatically returns a 307 and redirects the caller to the route with a /.
What is strange is that this has caused Google cloud run to return a 403 for the route without the trailing slash and a 200 as soon as the slash is added.
To me this seems very odd behaviour and I would love to hear if anyone can she light on why this has happened.
I described all that has been tried, and have added a small repro.

Can you share the header provided in the response? in addition, can you share your flask app configuration? Sometime, trailing/missing / are not supported, depending on the configuration.

It is not a flask app, it is a FastAPI app. Also "provide configuration" is a little unclear - the full app has a lot of configuration which would not make sense to past onto SO.

I'm not a python developer and I never used FastAPI before. But I observed locally and on Cloud Run the same thing about the 307 redirect. But impossible to get a 403 when I hit the endpoint with a /. I get a usual 307. So, impossible to reproduce your case. Can you share a minimal code sample to allow us reproduce your context?

Hey @guillaumeblaquiere yeah sure - let me pull it together, but if you have a small demo - just checking if it is behind a load balancer? I am now thinking this could have been the culprit.

No, I didn't test behind a load balancer. Will do, and let you know
